# count lines in each file in multiple subdirectories

Tags: bash, hadoop, hdfs

I need to loop through multiple directories on HDFS. I want to print out the name of each file, and the number of lines in that file.  I've got it almost working, except there is a line break between the file name and the count.  Here's my code:

```
for filename in `hdfs dfs -ls /path/to/main/directory/*/*part* | awk '{print $NF}' `; do echo $filename ; hdfs dfs -cat $filename | wc -l; done  > foo.out
```

In the output, I get:

```
/path/to/file1
# of rows
/path/to/file2
# of rows
```

...
How do I keep it from breaking after the file name?

Comment: Use `printf '%s: " "$filename"` instead of `echo $filename`

Comment: Well, that was easy, thanks! I did have to replace the first double quote with a single quote.

Answer (score 0):

If we breakdown the code of for loop, two commands are executed in sequence first echo command followed by hdfs command which is why the output is with a line break. There are multiple ways to achieve desired output but below are my two cents.

**Method 1:** To omit the trailing newline from echo using -n option.

```
for filename in `hdfs dfs -ls /path/to/main/directory/*/*part* | awk '{print $NF}' `; do echo -n $filename; hdfs dfs -cat $filename |wc -l; done > foo.out
```

With the above approach, you will get filename and count without any space or delimiter in between. You can add space or any delimiting character in the echo statement itself.

```
echo -n "$filename : ";
```

**Method 2:** To combine echo and the hdfs commands into a single line by using backquote(acute) to execute hdfs command in the echo statement.

```
for filename in `hdfs dfs -ls /path/to/main/directory/*/*part* | awk '{print $NF}' `; do echo "$filename : `hdfs dfs -cat $filename |wc -l`"; done > foo.out
```